# Cannot start cluster from namenode (master): different $HADOOP_HOME on datanode (slave) and namenode (master)

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am using Hadoop 1.2.1 on master and slave but I have them installed on different directories. So when I invoke `bin/start-dfs.sh` on master, I get the following error.

```
partho@partho-Satellite-L650: starting datanode, logging to /home/partho/hadoop/apache/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-partho-datanode-partho-Satellite-L650.out
hduser@node2-VirtualBox: bash: line 0: **cd: /home/partho/hadoop/apache/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/..: No such file or directory**
hduser@node2-VirtualBox: bash: **/home/partho/hadoop/apache/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: No such file or directory**
partho@partho-Satellite-L650: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/partho/hadoop/apache/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-partho-secondarynamenode-partho-Satellite-L650.out
```

The daemons are getting created fine on the Master as you can see below

```
partho@partho-Satellite-L650:~/hadoop/apache/hadoop-1.2.1$ jps
4850 Jps

4596 DataNode

4441 NameNode

4764 SecondaryNameNode
```

It is obvious that Hadoop is trying to find the `hadoop-daemon.sh` and `libexec` on the slave using the `$HADOOP_HOME` on the master.

How can I configure individual datanodes/slaves so that when I start a cluster from master, the Hadoop home directory for the respective slaves are checked for `hadoop-daemon.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

Once you set up the cluster, to start all daemons from master

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format(if required)
bin/stop-dfs.sh
bin/start-dfs.sh
bin/start-mapred.sh
```

In order to start all nodes from master,

```
- you need to install ssh on each node
- once you install ssh and generate ssh key in each server, try connecting each nodes from master
- make sure slaves file in master node has all Ips of all nodes
```

So commands would be

```
- install ssh(in each node) : apt-get install openssh-server
- once ssh is installed,generate key : ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
- Create password less login from namenode to each node:
  ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@datanodeIP
  user - hadoop user on each machine`enter code here`
- put all nodes ip in slaves(in conf dir) file in namenode
```

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop usually sets the HADOOP_HOME environment variable on each node in a file named hadoop-env.sh.

You can update hadoop-env.sh on each node with the path for the respective node. It should maybe be in /home/partho/hadoop/apache/hadoop-1.2.1/. Probably want to stop the cluster first so it will pickup the changes.

If you have locate installed run
locate hadoop-env.sh
or find / -name "hadoop-env.sh"

Answer (score 0):

For Best solution for this you should keep hadoop directory in your any directory but it should be same for both like Example:

on master path:

```html
/opt/hadoop
```

on slave path

```html
/opt/hadoop
```

it doesn't matter which version you are using but directory name should be same

Comment: The version should matter. Hadoop3 properties wouldn't work on Hadoop 2 or 1

Comment: why not it's work fine if you having hadoop3 on master and hadoop2 on slave but directory name should as hadoop only on both it will take data from master and search same configuration file on slave.

Comment: Directory names and locations are not important. The protocol used by the clients talking to the master and the properties that they read from the files matter.

Comment: For example, if you had a property file with YARN Docker containers enabled and Erasure Coding HDFS settings, that'll only work on Hadoop3, not anything less

Comment: APIs are supported by hadoop in hadoop 3 ,2, 1 are compatible

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

### On Master-Side

#### hadoop-daemons.sh

In `$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh` (not `$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh`, there is an `s` in the filename), there is a line calling `$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/slaves.sh`. In my version (Hadoop v2.7.7), it reads:

`exec "$bin/slaves.sh" --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR cd "$HADOOP_PREFIX" \; "$bin/hadoop-daemon.sh" --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR "$@"`

Change the line it to the following line to make it respect slave-side environment variables:

`exec "$bin/slaves.sh" "source" ".bash_aliases" \; "hadoop-daemon.sh" "$@"`

#### yarn-daemons.sh

Similarly, in `$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/yarn-daemons.sh`, change the line:

`exec "$bin/slaves.sh" --config $YARN_CONF_DIR cd "$HADOOP_YARN_HOME" \; "$bin/yarn-daemon.sh" --config $YARN_CONF_DIR "$@"`

to

`exec "$bin/slaves.sh" "source" ".bash_aliases" \; "yarn-daemon.sh" "$@"`

### On Slave-Side

Put all Hadoop-related environment variables into `$HOME/.bash_aliases`.

### Start / Stop

To start HDFS, just run `start-dfs.sh` on master-side. The slave-side data node will be started as if `hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode` is executed from an interactive shell on slave-side.

To stop HDFS, just run `stop-dfs.sh`.

---

### Note

The above changes already are already completed. But for perfectionists, you may also want to fix the callers of `sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh` so that the commands are correct when you dump them. In this case, find all occurrences of `hadoop-daemons.sh` in the Hadoop scripts and replace `--script "$bin"/hdfs` to `--script hdfs` (and all `--script "$bin"/something` to just `--script something`). In my case, all the occurrences are `hdfs`, and since the slave side will rewrite the command path when it is `hdfs` related, the command works just fine with or without this fix.

Here is an example fix in `sbin/start-secure-dns.sh`.

Change:

`"$HADOOP_PREFIX"/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR --script "$bin"/hdfs start datanode $dataStartOpt`

to

`"$HADOOP_PREFIX"/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR --script hdfs start datanode $dataStartOpt`

In my version (Hadoop v2.7.7), the following files need to be fixed:

- `sbin/start-secure-dns.sh` (1 occurrence)
- `sbin/stop-secure-dns.sh` (1 occurrence)
- `sbin/start-dfs.sh` (5 occurrences)
- `sbin/stop-dfs.sh` (5 occurrences)

---

## Explanation

In `sbin/slaves.sh`, the line which connects the master to the slaves via `ssh` reads:

```sh
ssh $HADOOP_SSH_OPTS $slave $"${@// /\\ }" \
   2>&1 | sed "s/^/$slave: /" &
```

I added 3 lines before it to dump the variables:

```sh
 printf 'XXX HADOOP_SSH_OPTS: %s\n' "$HADOOP_SSH_OPTS"
 printf 'XXX slave: %s\n' "$slave"
 printf 'XXX command: %s\n' $"${@// /\\ }"
```

In `sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh`, the line calling `sbin/slaves.sh` reads (I split it into 2 lines to prevent scrolling):

```sh
exec "$bin/slaves.sh" --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR cd "$HADOOP_PREFIX" \; \
 "$bin/hadoop-daemon.sh" --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR "$@"
```

The `sbin/start-dfs.sh` script calls `sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh`. Here is the result when `sbin/start-dfs.sh` is executed:

```
Starting namenodes on [master]
XXX HADOOP_SSH_OPTS: 
XXX slave: master
XXX command: cd
XXX command: /home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7
XXX command: ;
XXX command: /home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh
XXX command: --config
XXX command: /home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7/etc/hadoop
XXX command: --script
XXX command: /home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7/sbin/hdfs
XXX command: start
XXX command: namenode
master: starting namenode, logging to /home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-akmacbook.out
XXX HADOOP_SSH_OPTS: 
XXX slave: slave1
XXX command: cd
XXX command: /home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7
XXX command: ;
XXX command: /home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh
XXX command: --config
XXX command: /home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7/etc/hadoop
XXX command: --script
XXX command: /home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7/sbin/hdfs
XXX command: start
XXX command: datanode
slave1: bash: line 0: cd: /home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7: Permission denied
slave1: bash: /home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: Permission denied
Starting secondary namenodes [master]
XXX HADOOP_SSH_OPTS: 
XXX slave: master
XXX command: cd
XXX command: /home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7
XXX command: ;
XXX command: /home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh
XXX command: --config
XXX command: /home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7/etc/hadoop
XXX command: --script
XXX command: /home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7/sbin/hdfs
XXX command: start
XXX command: secondarynamenode
master: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.7/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-akmacbook.out
```

As you can see from the above result, the script does not respect the slave-side `.bashrc` and `etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh`.

---

## Solution

From the result above, we know that the variable `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR` is resolved at master-side. The problem will be solved if it is resolved at slave-side. However, since the shell created by `ssh` (with a command attached) is a non-interactive shell, the `.bashrc` script is not loaded on the slave-side. Therefore, the following command prints nothing:

```sh
ssh slave1 'echo $HADOOP_HOME'
```

We can force it to load `.bashrc`:

```sh
ssh slave1 'source .bashrc; echo $HADOOP_HOME'
```

However, the following block in `.bashrc` (default in Ubuntu 18.04) guards non-interactive shells:

```sh
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

At this point, you may remove the above block from `.bashrc` to try to achieve the goal, but I don't think it's a good idea. I did not try it, but I think that the guard is there for a reason.

On my platform (Ubuntu 18.04), when I login interactively (via console or ssh), `.profile` loads `.bashrc`, and `.bashrc` loads `.bash_aliases`. Therefore, I have a habit of keeping all `.profile`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_logout` unchanged, and put any customizations into `.bash_aliases`.

If on your platform `.bash_aliases` does not load, append the following code to `.bashrc`:

```sh
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Back to the problem. We could therefore load `.bash_aliases` instead of `.bashrc`. So, the following code does the job, and the `$HADOOP_HOME` from the slave-side is printed:

```sh
ssh slave1 'source .bash_aliases; echo $HADOOP_HOME'
```

By applying this technique to the `sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh` script, the result is the **Short Answer** mentioned above.